# In ReactiveExtensions how to select element from enumberable of elements?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming

As usual its difficult to explain my Rx question so ill let the code do the talking:

```
public class Feature
{
    public ReactiveProperty<bool> IsRunning = new ReactiveProperty<bool>(false);
}

public class MyHelpers
{
    public static ReadOnlyReactiveProperty<Feature> GetRunningFeature(IEnumerable<Feature> features)
    {
        // How do I return the latest running feature?
        // AND support disposing so no memory leaks
    }
}

public class TestMyHelpers
{
    public void Tests()
    {
        var features = new List<Feature>() {new Feature(), new Feature(), new Feature()};
        var running = MyHelpers.GetRunningFeature(features);

        features[1].IsRunning.Value = true;
        Assert.AreEqual(features[1], running.Value);

        features[2].IsRunning.Value = true;
        Assert.AreEqual(features[2], running.Value);

        features[2].IsRunning.Value = false;
        Assert.AreEqual(features[1], running.Value);

        features[1].IsRunning.Value = false;
        Assert.AreEqual(null, running.Value);
    }
}
```

Basically I want a solution that returns me the latest running feature given an initial input of IEnumerable of features and do it in a way that doesnt leak memory?

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I think I found the answer but if anyone knows of a better way of doing it im open to suggestions:

```
public static ReadOnlyReactiveProperty<Feature> GetRunningFeature(IEnumerable<Feature> features)
        {
            return Observable.Create<Feature>(obs =>
                {
                    var disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

                    foreach (var feature in features)
                        feature.IsRunning.Subscribe(_ =>
                                obs.OnNext(features.First(f => f.IsRunning.Value)))
                            .AddTo(disposables);

                    return Disposable.Create(() => disposables.Dispose());
                })
                .ToReadOnlyReactiveProperty();
        }
```